# Cron job to output json

Tags: json, bash, cron

I have been told this is not possible since cron jobs are based in bash scripting which does not offer support for output to json. After doing many google searching I was not able to find much on it. Can anyone tell me its possible to have a cron job output to json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are wanting to have a program run at a certain/period and return json to somewhere, may I suggest that you use some java code and the Quartz Scheduler see http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

Answer (score 0):

your php/bash script can create a .json file. that json file can be ouputed / send / transmit by your website